# Edit AstNode using JDT Exception: ASTnode cannot be modifed

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to rename a variable using AST and JDT:

At this point I can retrieve the ASTnode of the wanted variable, and the `getNodeType()` method returns that the retrieved **ASTnode is a "SimpleName"**,
Here is the code snippet that I use to set the variable name:

```
ASTNode an=nf.getCoveringNode();
SimpleName sn= ast.newSimpleName("rename_type");
 
if (an.getParent() instanceof SimpleType) {
    SimpleType st= (SimpleType)an.getParent(); 
    Name n=ast.newName("newname");
    st.setName(n);
}
```

Now it throws:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AST node cannot be modified.

Have you an idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Cite from `SimpleType` javadoc: `Type node for a named class type, a named interface type, or a type variable.`
So, first of all, you trying to change some type name, not variable name.

Do [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13054545/882813) is what you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yes I'm trying to change a type name.
I found the post you shared but it is not really what I look for, I have to use jdt AST API only

Comment: You probably need an `ASTRewriter`. [Vogella's article](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html#adding-imports-with-astrewrite) can be used as a starting point.

Comment: I read the vogella tuto also, I tried to use the rewriter but the exception appears before the compiler achieve the rewriter ( in the `setName method call)